# When i try to run Glue job using python to Relationalize array and struct data

Tags: aws-glue

When i try to run Glue job using python to Relationalize array and struct data I'm getting below error

```
INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
```

Any one know the resolution for this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no error. The `INFO` flag already tells you that this is not an error and nothing you need to worry about.

Is the job succeeded or not?

Comment: Thank you Robert 
Yes it successfully executed but didnt created the json file in s3buckets